# Change CSS of first <strong>

Tags: html, css

I want to change the CSS of `<strong>` element as below:

```
<p><strong>Make it Bold</strong><p>
<p>This is dummy text<strong>Do not make it BOLD</strong></p>
<p><strong>Make it Bold 2</strong><p>
<p>This is dummy text<strong>Do not make it BOLD 2</strong></p>
```

Can I somehow make a change `<strong>` CSS where I have written 'Make it Bold', the `<strong>` elements should only be bold if there is no text between the opening `<p>` tag and the opening `<strong>` tag<sup>1</sup>.

```
.strong{
   font-size: 30px;
}
```

I tried it with above CSS but I know it will change all strong elements; how can I achieve my particular requirement?

> P.S.: I cannot any additional classes

---

1. Paraphrased from the following comment:

   > [I] want element to be bold only if string exists right after `<p>`.. if there is any text before strong then that strong tag shall not be turned bold.

<sub>Quoted from comment, below: [Change CSS of first <strong>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42876681/change-css-of-first-strong#comment72857400_42876681).</sub>

Comment: <p class=".change"><strong>Make it Bold</strong><p>
.change{
 font-size: 30px;
}

Comment: You want the `<strong>` elements to be not-bold based on what criteria? When it's contained within even-numbered paragraphs (`p:nth-child(even) strong { font-weight: normal; }`? Or when the entire text-content of the parent paragraph is wrapped within the `<strong>` element (for which you'd need JavaScript)?

Comment: i can not add class.. as this is text from Database

Comment: That is no reason to be unable to add a class-name; although you may have to use JavaScript to do so.

Comment: i want element to be bold only if string exists right after <p>.. if there is any text before strong then that strong tag shall not be turned bold

Comment: Then CSS alone can't help you, you'll either need to add a class-name or use JavaScript; there's no selector for plain, unwrapped, text so all `<strong>` elements will match the same selector.

Comment: Feels like work.  Requirements keep changing.

Answer (score 3):

The :first-of-type selector allows us to target the 1st occurence of an element inside it's container.

```
p strong:first-of-type {
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

I hope I helped some people who are facing the same situation

Answer (score -1):

you can give a class or id to your strong element.
In your current code there are no classes.
You can use, for example:

```
<p><strong class="big">Make it bold</strong></p>
```

And in css

```
.big{
font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: i can not add any additional classes

Comment: then you can use pseudo-selectors.
like strong: first{
or nth-child selector
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: can't use addition class

Answer (score -2):

Use the `:first-child` [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).  [JSFiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/1y1Lcrke/)

```
:first-child strong {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Comment: `:first` is not a CSS pseudo-class relevant to this situation, it's for printed media (from the linked resource).

Comment: You are correct.  In the process of fixing my mistake.